# I want to redirect where VB2017 community saves projects

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have the location to do the changes but do not understand why there are three settings.

I teach `VB` at the university and `VB`, by default, saves student work to the `C` drive.  Needless to say, it is fraught with complications such as that the student has to return to that same computer if they forget to change the save location.

Do I need to redirect all three options?
Please explain why three locations are needed.

[image: Tools/Options/Projects and solutions]

Comment: No only the first option would be enough I would say, the rest are the templates available

Comment: The titles/lables tell you what each is for: projects, project template storage and item template storage.  Needless to say, please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

The **Projects location** is the default path where Visual Studio projects are stored. If I understand your question completely, this is the path that would change from student to student.

The **Project templates location** is the location where custom project templates can be stored. The **Item templates location** is the location where custom item templates can be stored. For more info, see [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx)